# Omitting ampersand in function call

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement ADT binary tree in C and I would like use API, which functions has form like foo(object, value). As far I wrote working tree for int value, but when I call BinTree_insert function I have to use operator"&" to get address of object. Is it possible to modify this function to omit & ?

```
typedef struct __bintree_node_t
{
    int data;
    struct __bintree_node_t* left;
    struct __bintree_node_t* right;
}bintree_node_t;

static void __BinTree_insert(bintree_node_t** node, int value)
{
    if(!(*node))
    {
        *node = __BinTree_newNode();
        (*node)->data = value;
    }
    else if((*node)->data < value)
        __BinTree_insert(&(*node)->left, value);
    else if((*node)->data > value)
        __BinTree_insert(&(*node)->right, value);
}

void BinTree_insert(bintree_node_t* node, int value)
{
    //??????
}

int main(void)
{
    bintree_node_t* root = 0;

    BinTree_insert(root, 2); //sth like this
    __BinTree_insert(&root, 1); //instead of this
}
```

Comment: Not if you want it to function as it does. Why would you want to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following options:

- Instead of modifying the passed pointer to a pointer, you could return a new pointer instead. But that means using the returned value, which defeats the encapsulation a bit:

  ```
  static void BinTree_insert(bintree_node_t* node, int value)
  {
      if (!node)
      {
          node = __BinTree_newNode();
          node->data = value;
      }
      else if (node->data < value)
          node->left = __BinTree_insert(node->left, value);
      else if (node->data > value)
          node->right = __BinTree_insert(node->right, value);
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      bintree_node_t* root = 0;

      root = BinTree_insert(root, 2);
  }
  ```
- Or if you just want to change the initial call, you could maintain the pointer-to-pointer yourself:

  ```
  int main(void)
  {
      bintree_node_t* root = 0;
      bintree_node_t** rootPtr = 0;

      __BinTree_insert(rootPtr, 2);
  }
  ```
- Or you could define a type which further encapsulates the pointer, but that adds quite a bit more code and memory allocation.

Not sure what the whole point is, though?

Answer (score 0):

You've implemented your insert() function so that it *modifies* its first parameter. To do that, you have to pass the root by pointer; if you passed it by value (a `bintree_node_t*`), a change of the root inside `BinTree_insert()` would not be reflected outside the function (though changes to the root *node* would be).

For example, if the tree is empty (root equals NULL), your insertion function creates a new node, and has the root pointer point at that node; that can't be done if you want to keep the original root pointer, which would continue being NULL.

What you could do is have the insertion function return the new root. Then you could pass the old root as a `bintree_node_t*` (i.e. by value).